# CStdioFile cannot work with files larger than 2GB?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, ftell, file-length

I am using Visual C++ 2008. In VC++ 2008, `CFile` supports 2^64 huge files. So I think `CStdioFile` should also support.

However, when using `CStdioFile::GetLength()` on a file larger than 2GB, I get a `CFileException`, below is the code snippet:

```
void CTestCStdioFileDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CStdioFile MyFile;
    CString strLine;
    ULONGLONG uLength;

    strLine = _T("This is a line.");

    if (MyFile.Open(_T("C:\\Temp\\MyTest.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareExclusive | CFile::typeBinary))
    {
        for (UINT uIndex = 0; uIndex = 200000000; uIndex ++)
        { 
            MyFile.WriteString(strLine);
            uLength = MyFile.GetLength();
        }

        MyFile.Close();
    }
}
```

After tracing into the `CStdio::GetLength()`, I find the following code snippet will raise exception, as below:

```
   nCurrent = ftell(m_pStream);            -> This will return -1
   if (nCurrent == -1)
      AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::invalidFile, _doserrno,
         m_strFileName);
```

It is amazing that `CStdioFile` still use `ftell` instead of `_ftelli64` to deal with the stream.

I then search the document for `CStdioFile`, I cannot find any document on `CStdioFile::GetLength`, the only related is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class?view=vs-2019#seek, and it asks me to see `fseek` document. But in `fseek` document, I still not find any related to file size limit.

Finally I find a third-party site that indicates `CStdioFile::GetLength` contains error: http://www.flounder.com/msdn_documentation_errors_and_omissions.htm#CStdioFile::GetLength, but it does not provide a solution.

Other than these, there are hardly any questions or posts on the 2GB limit of `CStdioFile` online. That is really strange.

I try to check the source code of `CStdioFile` iN VC++ 2017 and it is same as that for 2008.

So whether there is a simple solution for the problem without rewriting the whole `CStdioFile` class?

Comment: It might be a limitation of [`ftell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64?view=vs-2019) which returns a `long`. Visual Studio `long` type is a 32-bit type, even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, that is the case. I just wonder if there is a simple solution for this problem?

Comment: Don't use `CStdioFile`? Is there a reason it's used in your program? If it's a legacy program that you need to maintain, have you thought of refactoring it to use e.g. `CFile` instead? Or inherit from `CStdioFile` and override [`GetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfile-class?view=vs-2019#getlength) (it's `virtual`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CStdioFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class) exists primarily for a single reason: It's [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class#cstdiofile) taking a `FILE*` argument. The purpose of this class is to wrap a C Runtime [file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/files-and-streams) and expose it through a `CFile`-compatible interface. The implementation inherits all of the C Runtime limitations, in particular the file size limit of 2GB.

To address this, there are several options:

1. If possible, drop the use of `CStdioFile` altogether. Unless you are interfacing with (legacy) C code, there's no striking reason to ever use it.
2. If that is not an option, derive a custom implementation from `CStdioFile` and `override` all class members that surface file-relative offsets (`GetPosition()`, `GetLength()`, `Seek()`). All other class members are unaffected, and can simply be inherited. (Note: Make sure to restore the current file pointer when implementing `GetLength()`.)

   Microsoft provides extensions to its C Runtime that offer 64-bit wide offsets ([_ftelli64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64) and [_fseeki64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64)).

If you need to go with option 2, the following extension to `CStdioFile` can be used as a drop-in replacement with support for files larger than 2GB.

*CStdioFileExt.h:*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <afx.h>

class CStdioFileExt : public CStdioFile
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CStdioFileExt)
public:
    ULONGLONG GetPosition() const override;
    ULONGLONG GetLength() const override;
    ULONGLONG Seek(LONGLONG lOff, UINT nFrom) override;
};
```

*CStdioFileExt.cpp:*

```cpp
#include "CStdioFileExt.h"

ULONGLONG CStdioFileExt::GetPosition() const
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ASSERT(m_pStream != NULL);

    auto const pos = _ftelli64(m_pStream);
    if (pos == -1L)
        AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::invalidFile, _doserrno, m_strFileName);
    return static_cast<ULONGLONG>(pos);
}

ULONGLONG CStdioFileExt::GetLength() const
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);

    auto const nCurrent = _ftelli64(m_pStream);
    if (nCurrent == -1L)
        AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::invalidFile, _doserrno, m_strFileName);

    auto nResult = _fseeki64(m_pStream, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (nResult != 0)
        AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::badSeek, _doserrno, m_strFileName);

    auto const nLength = _ftelli64(m_pStream);
    if (nLength == -1L)
        AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::invalidFile, _doserrno, m_strFileName);
    nResult = _fseeki64(m_pStream, nCurrent, SEEK_SET);
    if (nResult != 0)
        AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::badSeek, _doserrno, m_strFileName);

    return static_cast<ULONGLONG>(nLength);
}

ULONGLONG CStdioFileExt::Seek(LONGLONG lOff, UINT nFrom)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ASSERT(nFrom == begin || nFrom == end || nFrom == current);
    ASSERT(m_pStream != NULL);

    if (_fseeki64(m_pStream, lOff, nFrom) != 0)
        AfxThrowFileException(CFileException::badSeek, _doserrno, m_strFileName);

    auto const pos = _ftelli64(m_pStream);
    return static_cast<ULONGLONG>(pos);
}

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CStdioFileExt, CStdioFile)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I choose option 2 as I need a buffered file class to improve the performance.